# How to reset file-associations to use the editor given in Content Types?

Tags: eclipse

I have a workspace with a lot of scss-files. Previously I opened some of them with "Open with -> Generic Text editor" or "Open with -> Text editor".

Now I installed LiClipseTex. I went to Preferences -> Generic -> Editors -> File associations and choose Liclipse SourceCss Editor for scss-file as default.

New scss-files are now opened corretly with the Liclipse SourceCss Editor when double-clicking, but the old files I already opened with Generic text editor ot text editor are still opened with that.

How can I reset all the files to be opened by the editor given in the file associations by default?

Comment: That should not happen in current versions of Eclipse. Are you sure that your Eclipse is up to date? Right-click one of these files and choose _Open With > Other..._, select the editor and check the checkbox _Use it for all '*.scss' files_. But again, your main problem seems to be that you missed to keep your software up to date.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I updated to "Eclipse for PHP Developers 2023-06" and do a full "search for updates" regulary, the last one yesterday. But I didn't know the trick going to "Other" and then be able to use the checkbox "Use for all *scss files". That works for all files but my style.scss file, there I now get "Unsupported content type in editor". Weird.

Comment: Hm, after deleteing and recreating the style.scss, it works here as well. No idea why. But thanks anyway!